# SharePoint REST request was working, suddenly returns 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an ASP.NET app that accesses SharePoint Online REST API using the `SharePointOnlineCredentials` class. The app was working for months, then recently started returning a `401 Unauthorized` error. It appears that only programmatic access is being blocked, because if I log into SharePoint Online in a browser and execute a REST request directly, I get valid results back. I don't think it is user-specific, because at least two different apps that access SharePoint (using two different user IDs) are now returning an error.

I took a look in Fiddler, and the direct, in-browser request uses a `FedAuth` cookie for authentication. The programmatic request using the `SharePointOnlineCredentials` class doesn't show any cookie or Authentication header.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
webClient.Credentials = _Credentials; // SharePointOnlineCredentials object
webClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
var uri = new Uri(restUri);
response = webClient.DownloadString(uri); // Returns 401
```

Something had to change that disallows programmatic access or a specific machine (the two apps tested are executing on the same server). Or, possibly, Basic Authentication got disabled/removed. I'm not really a "SharePoint guy", so I don't which, if any, of these are possibilities.

I asked our SharePoint admins, but so far they haven't uncovered any reason for this change in behavior. What could have changed that would suddenly deny access to all users when making a programmatic request in this way?

Comment: A password changed and your app doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We received a response from MS regarding this issue just a few minutes ago:

> We are aware of this situation and we are planning to make some changes to fix it in the course of next couple weeks. A workaround at this point is to pass in Cookies instead of Credentials.
>
> `$webSession.Cookies.SetCookies($siteURL, $authenticationCookies)`

**UPDATE**
Evidently MS fixed what they broke, because my app is working again, without having made any changes.

Comment: I just received the same email from them regarding my ticket. Checked my code and its working again!  magic :)

Answer (score 2):

Exact same issue for me!  Slightly different code but same idea, been working for over a year then suddenly yesterday it stopped and reported 401 unauthorized on my response.  I'm logging a ticket with Microsoft to get more info via our enterprise support contract.  Will update this when I hear back, please do the same if you get any other feedback.

**NOTE:** Password is not an issue, I can run this call directly from the browser (chrome) but using the SharePoint.Client assembly its failing

```
string reqURL = _appSettings.ExtBaseURL + "/" + siteCollectionURL + "/_api/web/RoleAssignments/groups";

        HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(reqURL);
        wreq.Method = "GET";
        wreq.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        wreq.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        wreq.Credentials = credentials;


        using (WebResponse webResponse = wreq.GetResponse())
```

Comment: I agree, it is not password, because I, too, can successfully execute in a browser, as indicated in my post. We are also considering opening a ticket with MS. I'll update if we do.

Comment: See [my answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/241485/69215).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and I traced it down to changing the assembly version from 1.0.0.0 to some other number in the calling assembly.  Changing my assembly back to 1.0.0.0 made it work again.